# Can't open python, possibly because of viruses

Tags: python, virus

I use windows 7 and I've had problems with viruses. Using eset nod 32 and malwarebite anti-malware I've managed to clean everything up. But now I can't open Python (neither Spyder nor ipython notebook...). Nod 32 tells me that there are some files that are damaged and can not be open in anaconda.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python, and googling my issue hasn't turned up anything. Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Remove previous installation of python, download the latest, install and attempt to launch python again.

https://www.python.org/downloads/

It could be that your anti-virus is false-identifying some python files as malicious, or perhaps you aren't installing python as administrator.

Perhaps python isn't on your path.

What happens when you open up your `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` program and run

```
python
```

Comment: I thought he said he did that

Comment: @ytpillai I think he updated his question with that, I don't recall seeing it when I replied.

Comment: @NuclearPeon I tried after you sugested it. And python is working perfectly if i open it through the cmd. I tracked de error and it seems to have some issue with the graffic interface. the error is the next one.
 "file "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\auth\login.py", line 88, incalidate_security.
 And other similar things and finaly: 
error: [Errno 10106] the requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.
I google the error but couldnt find anything related to my specific problem.
Thks for the help btw.

Comment: @PedroLago It looks like bad credentials, or it cannot contact the server. I think you mean `line 88, validate_security`, see https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.html.auth.login.html . Could a firewall be blocking the service?

Answer (score 0):

How did you uninstall python? By deleting the folder? Don't do that, there may be other data from it on your computer. Instead, go to `add or remove programs` and uninstall it from there (may be slightly different on Windows 7 beecause I am using 8.1)

Now, with your viruses, I would suggest that you take a hard drive and save the folders that you KNOW do not have viruses. This means folders that you made yourself, not ones that another application made for you. Back them up, then restore your computer to factory settings. This should erase all the viruses.